# Set a rule MySQL - If field A is x then field B can't be NULL

Tags: mysql

I have column entidade set to NULL but I want it to be NOT NULL if the user set column level to value 4. I already check on javascript that if a user select a level of 4 then entidade couldn't be NULL but how can I achieve the same on MySQL?

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  password CHAR(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  salt CHAR(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  level BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  entidade INT UNSIGNED NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY username (username),
  UNIQUE KEY email (email),
  FOREIGN KEY (level) REFERENCES levels(idlevel),
  FOREIGN KEY (entidade) REFERENCES entidade(identidade)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_users
BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.level = IF(NEW.level = 4 AND NEW.entidade IS NULL, NULL, NEW.level);

CREATE TRIGGER tg_bu_users
BEFORE UPDATE ON users
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.level = IF(NEW.level = 4 AND NEW.entidade IS NULL, NULL, NEW.level);
```

The trick is to violate `NOT NULL` constraint on one the columns (I chose it be `level`) if your condition is met.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0a522/1)** demo. *Try to uncomment the last insert statement and do `Build Schema`.*

If you're using MySQL 5.5 or higher and want a more meaningful error message to be produced then you can use [`SIGNAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) syntax.